# Reading a directory file by file

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Is it possible to read files from a directory one file after another?

I look for something like:

```
while (File file = Directory.GetFile(path)) {
    //
    // Do something with file
    //
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

I already knew about GetFiles() but I'm looking for a function that return one file at a time.

EnumerateFiles() is .Net4.x, would be nice to have, but I'm using .Net2.0. Sorry, that I didn't mention.

**(Tag updated)**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Comment: why can you not use `GetFiles()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate over the file names:

```
foreach(string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)) {

    // Do something with fileName - using `FileInfo` or `File`

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");

foreach (var sFilename in arfiles)
{
    // Open file named sFilename for reading, do whatever
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(sFilename )) 
    {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
    var currFileText = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`Directory.GetFiles(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method?

```
foreach(String fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...

```
 foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                // Further processing
            }
```